ESM url scheme error in quasar cli with webpack v4
after creating a new project using the latest v4 of webpack in quasar framework i see this error
Error [ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ESM_URL_SCHEME]: Only URLs with a scheme in: file, data, and node are supported by the default ESM loader. On Windows, absolute paths must be valid file:// URLs. Received protocol 'c:'
    at throwIfUnsupportedURLScheme (node:internal/modules/esm/load:239:11)
    at defaultLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/load:130:3)
    at ModuleLoader.load (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:396:13)
    at ModuleLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:278:56)
    at new ModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:67:26)
    at #createModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:290:17)
    at ModuleLoader.getJobFromResolveResult (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:247:34)
    at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:228:17)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:315:23) {
  code: 'ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ESM_URL_SCHEME'
}

Node.js v20.16.0

when im using the webpack v3 nothing is wrong but since the webpack v4 was introduce i try it but i dont know how to solve this issue
pelase give me some guidance

I have the exact same issue, it seems @quasar/app-webpack 4.0.0-beta.23 introduced it, if you need v4 you can use 4.0.0-beta.22. I could not find any absolute imports in my project so it must come from somewhere else.

@Kalidasya are you able to find solution in this issue?

I have checked a bunch of commits, checked my precompiled files, went through the quasar upgrade guide and adjusted my code here and there, updated nodejs, but nothing, I dont even know what module it tries to load because its not logged.

@Kalidasya anyway if you find way please answer this question bro, right now i switch back to legacy webpack 3
